# Exclude some directories while Copying Data on Hadoop Cluster using hadoop distcp

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing, hadoop2

Is there any way to skip some directories while copying hadoop data from one cluster to another cluster? I.e. I am copying some data from my existing cluster to new cluster but i don't want to copy current month  data.

```
    /user/username/year=2021/month=06/day=01
    /user/username/year=2021/month=06/day=02
    .
    .
    .

    /user/username/year=2021/month=07/day=01
```

I don't want to include month 07's  data. How can i skip current months directories?

I am trying to use filters in command but it is not working for me.

1st  Approach:

```
    hadoop distcp  -filters /user/username/year=2021/month=07/day=0.*
     -skipcrccheck 
    -update webhdfs://<src_host>:port/user/username/year=2021/month=07
    webhdfs://<target_host>:port/user/username/year=2021/month=07
```

so that it can filter days less than 10 ie(01,02,03,...09) but its not taking this * and showing warning.

In logs  its showing can not find filters

webhdfs://<src_host>:port//user/username/year=2021/month=07/day=0.*

Even I tried by giving complete path till filename.

```
   I.e. webhdfs://<src_host>:port/user/username/year=2021/month=07/day=01/myfile.txt but it's showing the same issue. Can't find the filter file.
```

When I Checked the log for filter file instead of taking // its showing / in path

**webhdfs:/<src_host>:port/user/username/year=2021/month=07/day=01/myfile.txt**

2nd Approach:

```
    created one file "myfilter" (/user/username/myfilter.txt)
```

```html
.*webhdfs://<src_host>:src_port/user/username/year=2021/month=07/hour=0.*
```

```
    hadoop distcp  -filters 
    webhdfs://<src_host>:src_port/user/username/myfilter.txt
    -skipcrccheck -update webhdfs://<src_host>: 
   <src_port>/user/username/year=2021/month=07/ 
    webhdfs://<target_host>: 
   <target_port>/user/username/year=2021/month=07/
```

Error:

```
    ERROR tools.RegexCopyFilter: Can't find filters file 
    webhdfs:/<src_host>:src_port/user/myfilter.txt
```

In Logs I saw this Issue after webhdfs its taking /(single /) but ideally it should be double(//) not sure if this is the issue kindly guide.​

Comment: Why you add `.` in your filter. Your file names don't have `.` inside. use `day=0?` and try again.

Comment: @Majid tried .Even I tried /user/username/year=2021/month=07/day=07/myfile.txt.still it's showing same issue can find filter file.

Comment: add your filter to filter file like this: `.*/user/username/year=2021/month=07/day=0.*` and test it

Comment: @hatef Alipoor Updated the question with 2nd Approach according to Your Comment. Kindly Check and suggest.

Comment: put filter file somewhere in your local machine and then pass its location to `distcp`

Comment: @Sonu any progress?

Comment: @hatef Alipoor Thanks alot, yes aftre creating this file in local it worked.